# Is it possible to know which column filter is cleared kendo grid using jquery?

Tags: jquery, filter, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with around 10/12 columns with filtering options on all column. Now I need to know which column filter is cleared. Is there any event on grid or datasource so that I can find filter clear event and also which column fired that event?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "key" },
      { field: "value" }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        { key: "key1", value: "10" },
        { key: "key2", value: "11" },
        { key: "key3", value: "21" },
        { key: "key4", value: "23"},
        { key: "key5", value: "33" },
        { key: "key6", value: "15"},
        { key: "key7", value: "4" },
      ]
    },
    filterable: true,
    filter: function(e) {
      if (e.filter == null) {
        console.log(e.field + " cleared filter ");
      } else {
         console.log(e.filter.logic);
        console.log(e.filter.filters[0].field);
        console.log(e.filter.filters[0].operator);
        console.log(e.filter.filters[0].value);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to clear all other filter which are already applied. I need to find out which column triggered the filter clear event.

Comment: Your code is good when I need to know whether there is any more filter or not. But from this code I'll not be able to find out whether filter on Key4 column has been cleared or not. I need to know whether particular column's filter has been cleared or not (filter on other columns may exist at that time).